# Where can I find a PHP/MySQL implementation of Charles Miller's "Persistent Login Cookie" solution?

Tags: php, mysql, security, cookies, session-cookies

I have seen time and again Charles Miller's "[Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/)" recommended here as the absolute **best** way of implementing "Remember me" functionality on a site (if you really, *really* need that feature, which I do).

However, I've scoured the web and I can't find *any* actual PHP/MySQL code implementing his solution, and since "security" was stressed about a *gazillion* times with regard to using "Remember me", I'm afraid to code it myself from scratch for fear that I will misunderstand something or make a mistake that will result in a massive security hole.

Since his solution is almost 10 years old and happens to be the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication/477578#477578) on SO regarding Persistent Login Cookies, surely there has to be some vetted PHP/MySQL code out there that correctly follows his solution without any unintended security holes.  (The closest thing I found was a Drupal module, but I don't use Drupal.)

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

After reading a question on StackOverflow I’ve been inspired to help him out by writing a PHP/MySQL implementation of Charles Miller’s “Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice” For this tutorial I’m going to assume you already have a PHP system with user login.

```
CREATE TABLE user_sessions (
  user_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  session VARCHAR(39) NOT NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, session)
);
```

First, we need to update the site when you login to store the session into the cookie. This code will go with your current login system.

```
if (/* Code that verifies credentials */) {
  // ... code to log user into session

  PersistentAuth::login($userId);
}
```

Second, we want to check if a new user to the site has cookie credentials. This code will go at the beginning of your code. It checks, first, are we already logged in in our $_SESSION? if not, try the cookie-based login.

```
if (/* !loggedIn() */ && ($userId = PersistentAuth::cookieLogin())) {
  // ... use $userId to log user into session 
}
```

Third, in accordance with Charles Miller’s article we cannot allow a user to the following sections if they are logged in via cookie:

- Changing the user’s password
- Changing the user’s email address (especially if email-based password recovery is used)
- Any access to the user’s address, payment details or financial information
- Any ability to make a purchase

Code:

```
if (PersistentAuth::isCookieLogin()) {
  // User is logged in via cookie and don't have access to this 
  // section. We need to ask them for the password. Maybe send 
  // them to some login page?

  // TODO ask for password or send to a password page
}
```

To get all the code for the PersistentAuth class checkout my site here: http://www.chrislondon.co/php-persistent-login/

With this PersistentAuth class there are a few changes you will have to make. One you’ll have to change the getDb() function to return an instance of your database. I’m using PDO in this example. I have it set up for every page refresh clear the database of old sessions. The best way to handle this is to use a cron. If you do set up a cron then change the USE_CRON flag to true in the class settings

Comment: Can you at least summarize the relevant parts here? We tend to discourage link-only answers, because of how frequently they die when sites move, get shut down, etc.